# Excel VBA - Array Formula returns #VALUE! (Error 2015) in case a cell contains more than 255 characters

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, array-formulas

Dear all I am using an array formula and pass the result to a VBA macro, which means the result of the formula is passed as array to my macro.

In some cases I get in the array a #VALUE (error 2015) and I have no clue why. When I play arround with the affected cell where it gets the data from then it is happening when the cell has quite an amount of characters (~3000 chars).

Has anyone a clue what I can try to solve the isuse?

formula:

```
{=arrayToCSV(removeElementsFrom2DimArray(IF('sheet'!$G$1:$G$2000=A1;'sheet'!$F$1:$F$2000)))}
```

the `IF('sheet'!$G$1:$G$2000=A1;'sheet'!$F$1:$F$2000)` part returns an array like `{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE... Value, Value, FALSE , ...}`. This one I pass to my mVBA function `removeElementsFrom2DimArray` to remove the FALSE elements

Now it seems that the `IF('sheet'!$G$1:$G$2000=A1;'sheet'!$F$1:$F$2000)` return in some cases `#VALUE(Error 2015)` for some of the elements i.e.  `{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE... #VALUE!, Value, FALSE , ...}`

```
Function removeElementsFrom2DimArray(ByRef arr() As Variant, Optional value As Variant = False) As String()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    If (IsArray(arr)) Then
      For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If (arr(i, 1) <> value) Then   --> Here happens the error that arr(i, 1) return #VALUE! Error 2015. Why?
                coll.Add (arr(i, 1))
            End If
      Next i
     End If
     removeElementsFrom2DimArray = collectionToArray(coll)
     Exit Function
     ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume
   End Function
```

**UPDATES**:

- I tried to modify to pass over arr as `Variant` or `ByVal`. It did not made any difference.
- I tried to modify to pass over arr as array `arr()` with and without the `()`. It did not made any difference.
- If I reduce the number of chars in the affected cell `'sheet'!$F$1:$F$2000` to  below 256 chars then it works!
- If I use just the formula `{=IF(sheet!$G$1:$G$2000=A1;sheet!$F$1:$F$2000)}` (array formula) then it works too!

so I assume there is a limitation in passing arrays from native formulas to own functions? So that values in the array with more than 255 chars get passed with #VALUE! error?

Any idea? I am using Excel 2010 Plus (v14.0.7)

Comment: I read somewhere once that arrays can only contain 350 non-zero numbers, so I'm guessing it has something to do with size limitations.

Comment: You can add a test for errors before the offending line.  See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230658/how-do-i-determine-if-an-error-is-in-any-cell-in-the-entire-workbook-with-excel) for multiple methods to do that.

Comment: testing for errors e.g. IsError(arr(i,1)) -- see comment in source code -- does not really help because I need the data from the cell for further processing

Comment: Might be easier to skip the array formula and handle the whole thing in your UDF.

Comment: Three things. 1. Perhaps the argument Byref Arr() As Variant should be without (). 2. What does your collection2Array function look like? 3. Perhaps the cell in question contains an Excel  # error so instead of value, test against CStr(value)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, 1. "ByRef arr" without "()" did not made any difference. The #VALUE! error is already in the argument "arr" when my function get called so it is not related to other "collection2Array()" function. 3. Yes the error is already there when it gets passed to my function. I assume it is a limitation of Excel when passing over arrays from native formulas to user defined functions