# VBA to search a specific worksheet for errors and pass back result to main macro

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, error-checking

I need a macro which will search for formula errors in a specific worksheet in a workbook.  This needs to work in multiple different workbooks with different worksheet names in each book.  Once it has completed the check, I want it to define a variable called SheetErrors as "1" if there are errors or "0" if there aren't any.  If it is "1", it then needs to be passed back to a main macro as I want it to exit the sub and display a message box stating that spreadsheet contains errors.

I have written the code below to find the errors:

```
Sub Error_Finder()

Dim celltxt As String
Dim SheetErrors As String

celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("A:FA").Text



If InStr(1, celltxt, "#NULL!") Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, "#NUM!") Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, "#REF!") Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, "#VALUE!") Then
   SheetErrors = "1"
   Else
   SheetErrors = "0"


End Sub
```

I can't find anything useful to me on Google for passing the SheetErrors variable back to the main macro.  Any light you can shed on it would be gratefully received, also, I'm pretty new to VBA, so if there is a better way of doing what I have done above, please let me know.

Thank you,

P

Comment: I think `IsError(range.value)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230658/how-do-i-determine-if-an-error-is-in-any-cell-in-the-entire-workbook-with-excel

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass something back you could consider making it a function instead. That would look something like this:

Edit: Thanks to K.Davis and Tim Williams for the suggestions

```
Function SheetErrors() As String

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:FA")
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).count = 0) Then
        SheetErrors = "0"
    Else
        SheetErrors = "1"
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: This will throw a run-time error ("no cells were found") if there are no errors on the sheet.  Also, you can't `Dim SheetErrors` - that's already declared by the function header

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware of that. Let me see if I can figure something out

Comment: I've edited it to address the issues raised by @TimWilliams

Comment: I would personally rather use `On Error Resume Next` over a `On Error GoTo` in the middle of an `If statement`. In *this particular situation*, this would be a _somewhat_ justified use of `Resume Next`.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs would something like the above suffice?

Comment: Much better. Anything that `GoTo` in the middle of any block statement - `If..Then`, `With..End With`, etc is something that should be avoided. `GoTo` in general should be avoided if possible.

Comment: this is getting nit-picky, but maybe we should check the err object to make sure the error number is 1004 (No cells were found) before we assume it is a 0 error count?

Comment: then again, 1004 is generic enough, it might not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful, but wanted something slightly different.  This code allows you to check every sheet and create a log of the output.

```
Sub Check_for_errors()
Dim shl As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, errcount As Long, r As Long

Set shl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
shl.Name = "Error Log"
r = 1
errcount = 0

On Error Resume Next

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Error Log" Then
        
        errcount = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Count
        If errcount > 0 Then
            shl.Cells(r, 1) = sh.Name
            shl.Cells(r, 2) = errcount
            r = r + 1
            errcount = 0
        End If
    End If
Next sh
    
End Sub
```